# how to prove this theorem using resolution refutation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm in a beginner discrete math and computing course and I'm working on proving these two theorems using resolution refutation but I'm not getting a contradiction at the end, which is why I'm confused.

**Theorem 1: `⊢((p /\ q) --> p)`**

so this becomes `((~p \/ ~q) \/ p)`, and the statements in here are `{ {~p \/ ~q}, {p} }` and when I negate the conclusion I get that `(~p\/~q)` and `~p` don't cancel out, so then where is the contradiction? shouldn't there be terms to cancel out `p` and `q` to result in a `⊥` (aka a contradiction)?

**Theorem 2: `⊢(~p --> (p --> (p --> q)))`**

I have a similar issue here: the statement becomes `{ {p}, {~p}, {p /\ ~q} }`. and once again, `p` and `~p` cancel out, leaving us with `p /\ ~q`. So where is the contradiction `⊥`

this is what my notes say about resolution refutation:

> Resolution Refutation
> • To prove , … ,  ⊢  using resolution refutation:
>
> 1. Convert 1, … ,, ¬ to a set of clauses
> 2. Iteratively generate new clauses by applying resolution rule and add them to . Stop when
> 3. The resolution rule generates ⊥, which means the entailment holds, or
> 4. The rule cannot be applied, which means the entailment does not hold

so I'm not sure if I don't understand it well, so if I'm doing something wrong...? please help :)

Comment: $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor p$ is obviously a theorem, because we have that $\lnot p \lor p \equiv \top$.

Comment: Having said that, if you want to prove it by Resolution, you have to consider its negation: $\lnot ((p \land q) \to p) \equiv ((p \land q) \land \lnot p)$. Thus, you have three clauses: $\{ p \}, \{ q \}$ and $\{ \lnot p\}$

Comment: See step 1. in the procedure written in your post: in order to prove $\psi$ from the set of premises, you have to add $\lnot \psi$ to that set.

Comment: thank you! so I would need to prove this `~(((p /\ q) --> p)) ⊢((p /\ q) --> p)` by adding the 3 clauses you mentioned to the original clauses {~p} {~q} and {p}?

Comment: Also would the clauses be separate like this {~p} {~q} and {p}, or all grouped into one because they're all in the same implication like this  {~p, ~q, p}?

Comment: NO; if you want to prove $\vdash ((p∧q)→p)$ you have to use Resolution starting with formula $¬((p∧q)→p)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.